# Automated Testing on graphic outputs

Tags: testing, graphics, tdd

I wonder is there any tool or standard methods to automatically testing programs that produce graphic outputs.

For example, a simple painting application is built allowing users to draw circles and rectangles in specific locations. The tests probably need to check whether the shapes are located in the exact place as specified.

My problem is: is there a standard way to automate the test procedure instead of letting tester manually check the outputs again and again?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, but the most important is, that the GUI part comes last.

The GUI is only responsible (or should be) for visualizing data. This implies that you have some underlying models and functionality, which is told to create a circle or rectangle at a certain position. You would usually test this first in order to make sure, your functionality does the right things and the underlying data is correct. Functionality and models can be fully covered by regular API tests.

Your particular question is to check, whether the visualization part is correct. You have IMHO two options for automation:

1. Use screenshots and diff the drawing canvas between a static expectation screenshot and the actual test result
2. Use tracing: You would take a screenshot from the canvas area and convert it to some vector image that allows you to check certain vectors for being at the right place

In general, GUI specifics such as the right color, exact placing are still human tasks. You can only try testing as much as you can using API tests and reduce the human part to a minimum.